# Trying to figure out how Summations

Tags: java

The question states that the method (public static int Sum (int[] input) should take an array of ints, and perform the following mathematics over the input data, X.

[image]

Here is my code I need to know if I'm doing this question correct.

```
package mathsassessment;

public class Sum {

    public static void main (String[] args){
        int[] arr1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5,};
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
            sum += arr1 [i];
        }
        System.out.println("Sum is : " + sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: No, you should create a method `public static int Sum (int[] input) `

Comment: Your  logic is good, but you need to put it in a `Sum()` method.

Comment: You have an extra comma in your array declaration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks reasonable, except you didn't put it in a method named `Sum`. Also, in Java 8+, you could sum things with a stream like

```
public static int Sum(int[] input) {
    return Arrays.stream(input).sum();
}
```